# connection pooling in Tomcat with singleton?

Tags: java, tomcat, singleton, datasource

I am using connection pooling in a web application which runs on Tomcat. And I set it up as given here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding

When I need a connection I am calling the following code which is in each request of the servlets

```
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)
        envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myDBName");
        con = ds.getConnection();
```

Should I initialise ds object as a singleton and get connections from this object instead of getting ds over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JNDI lookups can be relatively expensive especially if you're going to do it over and over again.  You can lookup the DataSource object once in the Servlet's init() method and store it away in a field where you can use it later in the service()/doPost()/doGet() methods.

Just make sure to shut down/clean up after the DataSource in the Servlet's destroy() method.